# SQL Server: Error when trying to use SUM in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql query where I want to retrieve the sum of the amount of sales in August 2005. Whenever I run this, I receive the error "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause". How can I fix this so it displays all columns and display the sum in my repsales.amount column?

```
SELECT *, SUM(repsales.amount) AS amount 
FROM repsales
WHERE repsales.saledate BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT rs.*, SUM(rs.amount) OVER () AS total_amount 
FROM repsales rs
WHERE rs.saledate BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31';
```

My answer is using `SUM` as an analytic/window function.  This means that each row will be assigned a value, as contrasted to using `SUM` with `GROUP BY`, where an aggregation of rows takes place.

Using `SUM(amount) OVER ()` defines the window to be the entire table.  That is, the sum will be the total sum of the amount.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the OVER clause does? I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is to state the column names one by one in the select and groupby statements. I.E. the example below groups by the data based department and category:

```
select rs.department,rs.category,sum(rs.amount) as SumAmount
from repsales rs
where rs.saledate BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31';
group by rs.department, rs.category
```

If you need all columns, you can save the resultset of the query above in a temp table (select ... into #temp from ...) and use it like:

```
select rs.*,t.SumSmount
from repsales rs
inner join #temp t on t.department=rs.department and t.category=rs.category
```

Answer (score 0):

insert the sum of amount into a temp table with the unique value columns dept,category etc ...

```
Select rs.salespersonID, rs.OtherUniqueColumes, Sum(rs.amount) AS Amout
INTO #tempSales FROM repsales
WHERE repsales.saledate BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31'
Group By rs.salespersonID, rs.OtherUniqueColumes
```

join the temp table with the original table to get all other columns

```
SELECT rs.*, t.Amount
FROM repSales rs INNER JOIN #tempSales t on rs.salespersonID = t.salespersonID AND rs.OtherUniqueColumes = t.OtherUniqueColumes

DROP TABLE #tempSales
```